# Mean energy harmonic oscillator

Tags: energy, harmonic-oscillator

I know that for a particle under the potential

$$V(x,y,z)=\frac{k}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

the equipartition theorem says that it contributes to the mean energy to $\frac{3k_BT}{2} $ (one half for each degree of freedom).

My question is: let's say we have a potential like this one, for instance 2 particles with an harmonic interaction potential, where $r_{eq}$ stands for the equilibrium point:

$$V(x,y,z)=\frac{k}{2}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-r_{eq})^2$$

Note that in this case the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ are coupled in the potential.

How would one compute the contribution of such a potential to the mean energy? Is there any analogy to the equipartition theorem in a case like this?

Comment: Is r here a vector, or is it a constant distance? If it is a vector it's inconsistent, and if it's a constant you'll have a ring of minima rather than a point.

Comment: It is a constant.

Comment: To correct Nuclear_Wizard, you would have a spherical surface, since there are three dimensions.